# Extremely Pedantic Ruby Style Debate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, styles

A coworker and I are implementing a repository pattern in our Rails app that abstracts away from ActiveRecord. We noticed today that we didn't yet support find taking an array. While attempting to do this, we came up with a number of different possible ways to write it.

The four possibilities are outlined in this gist: https://gist.github.com/jseakle/6875446

My coworker was originally in favor of #1. I preferred #2, since it more closely resembled how AR does it, and would thus be less likely to cause confusion to new developers starting to work with this code. But then he raised the issue that the argument name now lies, so we generated the idea in 3. But of course, then the name was lying as it was being used, so we came up with 4, which solves all the theoretical problems, but is awfully long and just a bit silly-looking.

I'd like to know which you all think is best, and what advantages and disadvantages you see in each.

Comment: Don't put code directly related to your question in a link on another site. You're asking us to chase it down, which discourages potential answerers, plus, once link-rot sets in, it will make your question worthless. As this question is really soliciting opinions, I don't think it's going to last long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree w/ Chris.

```
def find(*ids)
  @source.find(*ids)
end
```

will work if `@source` is an instance of `ActiveRecord::Base` and can be called like

```
find(1)
find(1,2,3)
find([1,2,3])
```

so it is also very flexible

Answer (score 1):

`ActiveRecord::Base#find` accepts as many ids as you want to hand it, either as separate arguments or as an array. I'd say the cleanest way to do it would just be send along `n` ids as `n` separate arguments. i.e.:

```
[1] pry(main)> ids = 1
=> 1
[2] pry(main)> Project.find(*ids)
  Project Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
=> #<Project:0x3fedc17ad980>
[3] pry(main)> ids = [1,2,3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
[4] pry(main)> Project.find(*ids)
  Project Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" IN (1, 2, 3)
=> #<Array:0x3fedc251ba54>
[5] pry(main)> Project.find(ids)
  Project Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" IN (1, 2, 3)
=> #<Array:0x3fedc2fc8164>
```

Because `*foo` is safe against either a single object or a collection of objects, I propose that it's the cleanest.

Answer (score 0):

I think #1 is clearest, and at this point I'd say that's most important.  It's not always my discriminator, but that example has the fewest lines, and/or the shortest ones, with the simplest expressions.  It just reads like one would expect.  My opinion, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in favour of option one. I do not prefer checking specific types, but check it it is able to behave like an array / responds to find_all.